# Is 2015 data available for small group plans?

Tags: data-request, healthcare-finder-api

We are using V3.0 of the Healthcare.gov Finder to access small group plans, but nothing is being returned for plans with effective date of 2015-01-01. Are small group plans available for 2015?

Comment: Can you expand your question to show what requests are working and what isn't working (perhaps with screenshots?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 2015 data is certainly available. Here is a sample request, that returns 309 plans for the Fairfax, VA area as of 12/08/2014:

```
curl 'https://api.finder.healthcare.gov/v3.0/getSMGPlanQuotes' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' --data-binary $'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<p:PlanQuoteRequest xmlns:p="http://hios.cms.org/api" xmlns:p1="http://hios.cms.org/api-types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://hios.cms.org/api hios-api-11.0.xsd ">\n  <p:Enrollees>\n    <p1:DateOfBirth>1984-01-01</p1:DateOfBirth>\n    <p1:Gender>Male</p1:Gender>\n    \n    <p1:Relation>SELF</p1:Relation>\n    <p1:InHouseholdIndicator>true</p1:InHouseholdIndicator>\n  </p:Enrollees>\n  \n\n \n    \n\n  <p:Location>\n    <p1:ZipCode>22031</p1:ZipCode>\n     <p1:County>\n         <p1:FipsCode>51059</p1:FipsCode>\n         <p1:CountyName>FAIRFAX</p1:CountyName>\n         <p1:StateCode>VA</p1:StateCode>\n      </p1:County>\n  </p:Location>\n  <p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>2015-01-01</p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>\n  <p:Market>SmallGroup</p:Market>\n  <p:IsFilterAnalysisRequiredIndicator>true</p:IsFilterAnalysisRequiredIndicator>\n  \n  <p:PaginationInformation>\n    <p1:PageNumber>1</p1:PageNumber>\n    <p1:PageSize>10</p1:PageSize>\n  </p:PaginationInformation>\n\n  <p:SortOrder>\n            <p1:SortField>BASE RATE</p1:SortField>\n            <p1:SortDirection>ASC</p1:SortDirection>\n  </p:SortOrder>\n  <p:Filter>\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n     \n      \n    \n</p:Filter>\n  \n</p:PlanQuoteRequest>\n' --compressed
```